# Firestore Security Rule: How to validate Incoming Read Requests with Subcollection Field Values

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore collection named 'users' that stores user information. Within this collection, there is a subcollection named 'shops,' containing documents listing the shops each user is permitted to access. The 'shops' subcollection includes a field named 'shopId,' which serves as a unique identifier for each shop.

Each incoming read request contains a 'shopId.' I am looking to create a Firestore security rule that validates each incoming request. Specifically, the rule should verify whether the 'shopId' in the incoming request matches the 'shopId' in the 'shops' subcollection of the user document associated with the request, then grant read permission to document from any collection with shopId matching the client request.

Here is my code, but are not working.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow read access to user documents if conditions are met
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null &&
        // Check if the user document exists and if the 'shopId' in the request matches the 'shopId' in the user document
        exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/shops/$(request.data.shopId)) &&
        request.data.shopId == resource.data.shopId;
      
      // Allow reading all documents under any collection for the specified shopId
      match /{collectionId}/{document=**} {
        // Check if the user document exists and if the 'shopId' in the request matches the 'shopId' in the user document
        allow read: if request.auth != null &&
          exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/shops/$(request.data.shopId)) &&
          request.data.shopId == resource.data.shopId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Herman, what did you try? Did you read this part of the documentation on Security Rules: [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?hl=en&authuser=0#access_other_documents) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I have updated my question to include my code

Comment: It sounds like each document in your `shops` subcollection contains a `shopId` value. That's not good enough though, as you can't search across a collection in security rules. The solution is to use the `shopId` as the document ID in the `shops` subcollection and then use rules line the ones in Davd's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Firestore security rules seem to have a logical error. To achieve the desired behavior, you need to ensure that the 'shopId' in the request matches at least one 'shopId' in the 'shops' subcollection of the user document associated with the request.
Here's an updated version of your rules:

```
/ Allow read access to user documents if conditions are met
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null &&
    // Check if the user document exists and if the 'shopId' in the request matches any 'shopId' in the user document's 'shops' subcollection
    exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/shops/$(request.data.shopId));
  
  // Allow reading all documents under any collection for the specified shopId
  match /{collectionId}/{document=**} {
    // Check if the user document exists and if the 'shopId' in the request matches any 'shopId' in the user document's 'shops' subcollection
    allow read: if request.auth != null &&
      exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/shops/$(request.data.shopId));
  }
}
```

}
}